# jQuery elements selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I can't simply find this information on API documentation, because i don't know how to call this properly. So the question:

I have this kind of jQuery selector usage:

```
var $table = $('#sort-table');          // id of <table>
var $rows = $('tbody > tr', $table);    // , $table ???
```

So what means the second parameter for $rows? And if you'd be so kind, could you, please, help me to find this in jQuery documentation?

Comment: It's the context as can be seen [here in the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the context parameter, it is equivalent to `$table.find('tbody > tr')`

The given selector `tbody > tr` will be look up inside teh given context `$table`.

Ex: In your page, you may have more than 1 table and you are interested in the rows on only one table in that case if you use the selector `$('tbody > tr')` will select all `tr`s across all tables. That is not what you want.

But in you pass the context as the table you are interested in as in `$('tbody > tr', $table)` then the selector `tbody > tr` will get executed only for the children of `$table` table, fetching only the desired `tr`s.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NgRmn/).

If you look at the demo the css attribute `$rows.css('color', 'red');` is applied only to the first table where as `$('tbody > tr').css('font-weight', 'bold');` is applied to all tables.

Answer (score 2):

> var $rows = $('tbody > tr', $table);

Here $table is context, according to [jQuery documents](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) `jQuery( selector [, context ] )`

```
$('tbody > tr', $table);
```

or

```
$table.find('tbody > tr');
```

The `context` is used to call find on it with given selection criteria

Comment: Thanks a lot, it realy helped :)

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd argument provides [*context*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) for the selection. Your `rows` variable will contain `tr` elements that are direct children of a `tbody` element, that are *descendants* of the element contained in `$table`.

You could also have written it like this, which in this case would behave exactly the same way:

```
var $rows = $("#sort-table tbody > tr");
```

The context argument is somewhat equivalent to the `.find()` method, so you could also have written it as this:

```
var $rows = $table.find("tbody > tr");
```

Answer (score 2):

it means find `tr` inside $table

this is similar  to calling

```
var $rows = $table.find('tbody > tr');
```

the second parameter `$('tbody > tr', $table);`  is context which is optional..

Answer (score 2):

It is called the context of a selector and is used to limit your query to a certain "range", specified by the jQuery-object that you use as context..

From the docs:

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting
>   at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for
>   the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.
>   For example, to do a search within an event handler, the search can be
>   restricted like so:

```
$( "div.foo" ).click(function() {
  $(  "span", this ).addClass( "bar" );
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ for further info on that

In your example that would mean that:

```
var $rows = $('tbody > tr', $table);
```

is the same as:

```
var $rows = $table.find('tbody > tr');
```

Answer (score 0):

See what is happening here:

```
var $table = $('#sort-table');  
var $rows = $('tbody > tr', $table);
```

In the first line of code variable `$table` is holding the table id `#sort-table`.

In the second line of code says find the `'tbody > tr'` in this `$table` only.

This can be written like this too:

```
var $rows = $('tbody > tr', '#sort-table'); 
  //-says find-^^^^^^^^^--in-^^^^^^^^^^^----this table
```

You can achieve this with find too:

```
var $rows = $('#sort-table').find('tbody > tr');
```

or

```
var $rows = $table.find('tbody > tr');
```